# function 'wp_enable_block_templates' not found

Tags: hooks

I'm currently working on my website and encountered a problem after updating to the latest WordPress version.

The error message I get is:

> call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback,
> function 'wp_enable_block_templates' not found or invalid function
> name in
> /www/doc/www.zanggroepvocalis.nl/www/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on
> line 303

I tried to delete line 303, but that didn't work. I also disabled the themes and plugins, but still no success. Any other suggestions?

Comment: "I tried to delete line 303" - **never** edit core files like the `class-wp-hook.php`! After all, that's not where the actual problem is. And it seems to me that the update was corrupted or incomplete, so try again via the Dashboard admin, or you could also [do it manually](https://wordpress.org/support/article/updating-wordpress/#manual-update). (You could try replacing just the `wp-includes` folder)

Answer (score 1):

Just to be sure, is *"last WordPress version"* the 5.8?

`wp_enable_block_templates` is a function added in the version 5.8 of WordPress. You should find it in `wp-includes/theme-templates.php` as you can see [here](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/ab2519189567c714d906ff782b9961b3988a2b48/wp-includes/theme-templates.php#L176-L186).

Check if that function is actually present in your file. If not, probably something gone wrong during the updating. How did you do that? Manually or from the dashboard?

As SallyCJ suggested, just a new correct updating should solve the problem.

Comment: That error won't let you see admin page either